# Sessions cannot work on accepted page

Tags: php, ajax, session, authentication, logout

**General info**

I worked all day to just solve this bug which I can't understand reason.

**Problem itself**

I set sessions on current page(index.php)

```
{index.php}
session_start();


$_SESSION['current_token']='123asd13gddsffa1231adf';
```

like `current_token` then I send this request with ajax to another page( login.php) then 
on the another page:

```
{login.php}

session_start();
echo$_SESSION['current_token'];
//output ''
```

result is '`''`'.

How It can be possible? All processes are going on same domain.

Please help I worked all day to solve this  but I couldn't.

Please help to solve this bug.

Comment: you have to change session settings **BEFORE** you do session_start(). starting the session automatically sends the session cookie with the settings in effect AT THAT TIME. There's no point in changing the settings later, because then it's already too late.

Comment: and `123asd13g...` is probably a syntax error. there's no quotes, it's not a valid number, blah blah blah.

Comment: @MarcB I used sessions start after settings and it doesnt affected anything.Also It is my false to not write ''.Okay I edited question and changed it with quotes version '1231asdas'

Comment: @MarcB maybe problem get sessions from page.For example similar with this example I have problem with logout,and I cant delete cookies,I used same name with path '/' but it doesnt affect anything.Can problem root be secure sessions orr cookies?